# php & operator construct

Tags: php

I got this piece of code which I'm analysing and it have this condition

```
if(($hint&self::HINT_WRITE  && $hint&self::HINT_NOWRITE) || ($hint&self::HINT_READ  && $hint&self::HINT_NOREAD))
{
    some code ..
}
```

Any Idea what '&' in '$variable&self::CONSTANT' means?

Comment: It's the bitwise `AND` operator

Comment: That's a very cramped-for-space bitwise AND

Comment: interesting names for the constants.